# Chrome Extension errors: Trailing comma not allowed and Dictionary keys must be quoted

Tags: json, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I am making a chrome extension and I need to change the icon of the extension.

manifest:

```
 {
    "name": "Extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Extension",
    "icons": {128: "icon_128.png"},
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
    },
    "manifest_version": 2,  
  }
```

the first problem is that in this line of code:
`"icons": {128: "icon_128.png"},`

it says: Manifest is not valid JSON. Line: 5, column: 15, Dictionary keys must be quoted.

the other problem is in this line of code:

```
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
    },
```

it creates this error

Manifest is not valid JSON. Line: 7, column: 5, Trailing comma not allowed.

I have no idea what is happening!?

Comment: remove `,` from here : `"default_icon": "icon.png",<---`

Comment: also remove `,` from `"manifest_version": 2,` and add quotes to `128:` so it becomes `"128":`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sample configuration

{
  "name": "Sample",
  "author": "Extension Developer",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Sample.",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": [ "input","activeTab","tabs","<all_urls>", "storage","debugger","activeTab","http://*/*","https://*/*"], 
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["js/background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon.png",
    "32": "icon.png",
    "48": "icon.png",
    "128": "icon.png"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
    
 }
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you still need an answer, but the reason why you got this error:

> the first problem is that in this line of code: `"icons": {128: "icon_128.png"},`
> it says: Manifest is not valid JSON. Line: 5, column: 15, Dictionary keys must be quoted.

is because you typed `"icons": {128: "icon_128.png},` and didn't quote the `128`. So it should be `"icons": {"128": "icon_128.png},`.

As for the second error you got, I don't know why the error is showing, I also get it in my extension, and I haven't figured out why I'm getting it.

I hope this solved your first error.

*edit
I figured out why you were getting the second error.
You typed:

```
{
   "name": "Extension",
   "version": "1.0",
   "description": "Extension",
   "icons": {128: "icon_128.png"},
   "browser_action": {
       "default_icon": "icon.png",
   },
   "manifest_version": 2,  
}
```

But the last line of code or what ever it's called (I'm new with coding) before the `}` shouldn't end in a `,`, which you did with both `"default_icon": "icon_128.png"` and `"manifest_version": 2`.

So the whole code should instead be:

```
{
   "name": "Extension",
   "version": "1.0",
   "description": "Extension",
   "icons": {128: "icon_128.png"},
   "browser_action": {"default_icon": "icon.png"},
   "manifest_version": 2  
}
```

I put the whole `"browser_action"` on one line to make it easier to see that there is no `,` on the last line of code before the `}`.

I hope you can understand this and that this helped you.